# Null Pointer Exception when loading SharedPreference value into fragment string

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, flickr

I'm receiving a null pointer exception when trying to load the string value from sharedpreferences into the string value on my fragment.

I have the sharedpreference working correctly, so I know the string is being saved, but I can't replace the string value in my fragment with the sharedpreference value.

**MainActivity**

```
SharedPreferences saveLocation = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveLocation.edit();
                        editor.putString("name", marker.getTitle());
                        editor.commit(); //applies the name to XML
```

**FlickrFragment**

```
public class FlickrFragment extends Fragment{
GridView mGridView;
ArrayList<GalleryItem> mItems;
ThumbnailDownloader mThumbnailThread;


String textToSearch = "Keating Hall";
```

Basically "Keating Hall" is the text that's being used to generate a gridview of photos. That works correctly, however, I'm trying to replace "Keating Hall" with the sharedpreference value, but have been unsuccessful in all methods that I've tried.

Please let me know if my description needs to be updated to better reflect what I need help with.

Thank you.

**Updated: Included LogCat**

```
12-14 15:12:25.161  14902-14902/com.example.ramap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ramap, PID: 14902
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.ramap.FlickrFragment.<init>(FlickrFragment.java:41)
        at com.example.ramap.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter.getItem(TabsPagerAdapter.java:25)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5150)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16660)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2058)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1374)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5905)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:807)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:601)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the nullpointer error message?

Comment: Just updated my post to include the logcat.

Comment: and which line is this occurring on? from your code that is

Comment: The FlickrFragment code I posted above works, but when I load the sharedpreference and then change the String textToSearch to the sharedpreference value, I receive the null pointer exception.

I'll post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: can you post the code that causes the error?  I can't help fix code that isnt broken

Comment: are you sure that *marker.getTitle()* don't return an empty string?

Comment: @QuinnFTW, give me one minute, just adding the code again.

Comment: Please post the code of FlickrFragment.

Comment: Um... do you have access to context in FlickrFragment? If you don't you can call that getsharedpreferences.

Comment: @user2260040 http://pastebin.com/jLiXLe1T

That is the code for FlickrFragment

Comment: @TrebiaProject.

I'm not completely sure if I do or not, I'm making a lot of effort to understand everything there is to know about Android development.

Comment: I suppose, to reinstate my question, I'm not sure how I'm suppose to setup loading the sharedpreference I stored in MainActivity so that it can be accessed in FlickrFragment so that I'm able to take the value and pass it to a string.

Comment: Could you show all your code? Context is only available in your activity, if it is a different class probably you don't have access.

Comment: @TrebiaProject. Sure, I will link the github branch that has all the code. 

My code is listed here: 
[link](https://github.com/josephleroy/RaMap/tree/presentation-branch/app/src/main/java/com/example/ramap)

Comment: @QuinnFTW Sorry for the delay. 

`public static final String SAVE = "MySavedLocations";

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String textToSearch = settings.getString("name", "nothing to load");`